# How to delete binding column from DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

how can I delete a column from my DataGridView after binding in DataSource property?

For example, my object is:

```
public class A 
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

Then I'm doing:

```
List<A> aList = new List<A>();

//add some values in aList

myDataGridView.DataSource = aList;
```

My DataGridView is showing columns for A, B and C and I want remove C column from that list.

Any suggestion will be appretiated.

Comment: Without modifying your class?

Comment: Yes.. I'm using this field in my business model

Comment: hiding the colun is not enough?

Comment: You can decorate the property with `[Browsable(false)]`. Also you can select a list containing properties which you need using linq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a simple option you can decorate the property with `[Browsable(false)]`. This way, the column will not be shown in grid when your columns are auto-generated:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public int c { get; set; }
```

Also you can use the `Displayname` attribute also to set column header text, for example if you decorate a property with `[DisplayName("Some Text")]` attribute,  *Some Text* will be shown as header text.

Another simple solution is selecting a list of objects containing those properties which you need from the original list using `linq`:

```
var aList = new List<A>();
dataGridView1.DataSource = aList.Select(x => new { a = x.a, b = x.b }).ToList();
```

Comment: The browsable attribute was exactly what I was searching for. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate class (DTO) which will have only `A` and `B`. Then create a list of that class and bind to the gridview.

(OR)

Create a `DataTable` with the necessary column -> fill that datatable and bind that as DataSource of your gridview.

(OR)

keep the column bounded to your gridview but hide it saying

```
myDataGridView.Columns["C"].Visible = false;
```